# Most recent record for multiple dates

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am linking two tables the **APVENMAST** and the **APVENDADDR**.
The **APVENDADDR** stores addresses based on the effective date (`Effective_Date`).  The report is showing all the prior addresses.  I am trying to extract the most recent date with the most recent address:

```
SELECT MAXIMUM ({APVENADDR.EFFECTIVE_DATE})
```

trying to exclude former addresses from the extract.

Comment: Hi @yvonne, your report is getting the data from some source. Can you share with us that source (maybe a view)? Also , what is the database where the data is located ? This question does not give us a lot to work with. Please help us help you :) Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` and `order by`.  I think this does the trick assuming the table has the same columns.

```
select . . .   -- whatever columns you want
from APVENMAST avm LEFT JOIN
     (select av.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY av.? ORDER BY av.Effective_Date) as seqnum
      from APVENDADDR av
     ) av
     on avm.? = av.? and av.seqnum = 1;
```

The `?` is for the column that links the tables.